# ¿Me sale error al agregar array en Mongodb compass?

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, mongodb

Me sale error al querer crear documento con un array
Error: **Insert not permitted while document contains errors.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Alexis Estrada Evangelista, el código debes ingresarlo como texto, sería interesante que agregarás los métodos que estén relacionados, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta a fin de realizar las modificaciones, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Ahi claramente dice que no pudo insertarlo porque el documento contiene errores... así por encima lo que veo es que por ejemplo la empresa BWR tiene una fecha de inicio y una de termino... pero a esos campos les falta la **coma** al final para que sean una sintaxis valida

Comment: Exactamente lo que dice @Pipe